# how to remove Mage_Review_Block_Helper?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I need to remove the Mage_Review_Block_Helper block from a product quickview, so I cannot delete the "$this->getReviewsSummaryHtml" string in the product view template. 
I tried "remove name="product.info.review", but has no effect.

thanks

Here is the xml layout:

```
<quickview_index_view_FINAL>
    <remove name="before_body_end" />
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>sns/quickview/product.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="product.info.upsell"/>
        <remove name="product.info.additional"/>
        <remove name="catalog.product.related"/>
        <remove name="product.info.product_additional_data"/>
        <remove name="product.review.form"/>
        <remove name="product_review_list.toolbar"/>
        <remove name="product.description"/>
        <remove name="product.attributes"/>
        <remove name="product.info.bought"/>
        <remove name="product.info.addto"/>
        <remove name="product.info.review"/>
    </reference>
</quickview_index_view_FINAL>
```

Comment: put code layout code and quickview code

Comment: hello, I added the xml code and the template one. However, it seems that the template code is not rendered.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.

Comment: you're right, the module is a third party, but it uses getReviewsSummaryHtml() from mage core. However, I found a simple solution just wrapping the function call in a standard block and then removing it from that module view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler solution, using a wrapper block calling $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml inside a phtml file.

I called it product.info.review_custom, so using:

```
<remove name="product.info.review_custom">
```

worked now.

Answer (score 0):

This component is not removable through the layout xml because the block is beeing created at runtime:

```
protected function _initReviewsHelperBlock()
{
    if (!$this->_reviewsHelperBlock) {
        if (!Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Review')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->_reviewsHelperBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper');
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

(app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php)

There are at least two possibilities, if you don't want to touch the product view template:

1. Disable the module output of Mage_Review in the backend, if you
   don't need it all over your store.
2. Do a class rewrite of **Mage_Review_Block_Helper** and overwrite the method **getSummaryHtml** with an empty output **return '';** You can add a condition before the return statement to check for the product view page or where ever you want to hide it.

Comment: thanks, why is not as simple as adding a remove tag in the quick view handle?